# what is the right way to read from the contract? using wagmi.sh

Tags: solidity, react, wagmi, sepolia

So I am using the package wagmi.sh and via that I am writing to a very simple contract called the counter program that increments the value by 1 each time I call the function. Now I am able to successfully increment it, however while using use effect , when it waits for the transaction to complete , I want it to fetch the value of the increment. It is unable to do it, not sure why?

````
'use client'
import { useContractRead,usePrepareContractWrite, useContractWrite  } from "wagmi"
import {useAccount } from "wagmi"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useWaitForTransaction } from 'wagmi'

const abi = [
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "counter",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getCounter",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "increment",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
]

export default function SimpleStorage(){
    const [countervalue,setCounterValue] = useState(0)
    const {address,isConnecting,isDisconnected,isConnected} = useAccount()
    const  [successStatus,setsuccessStatus] = useState(false)
    console.log(isConnected)
    console.log(address)
    const {data:CounterValue,isError,isLoading} = useContractRead({
        address:"0x9a2b8157348F2D04154e8f79b09EB77D2c506A17",
        abi:abi,
        functionName:"getCounter",
    })
    if(!isLoading){
        console.log("The counter value is ",(CounterValue).toString())
    }
    
    const { config:increment, error } = usePrepareContractWrite({
        address: '0x9a2b8157348F2D04154e8f79b09EB77D2c506A17',
        abi: abi,
        functionName: 'increment',
        })
    const {data:value, write,isSuccess } = useContractWrite(increment)
    
    
    const {data:waitTransaction,isFetched} = useWaitForTransaction({confirmations:2,hash:value?.hash})

    if(isFetched === true){
        setsuccessStatus(true)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getCounterValue()
    },[successStatus===true])  
      
    
    
    async function getCounterValue(){
        const counter = await CounterValue.toNumber()
        console.log("Runnin the counter script",counter)
        setCounterValue(counter)
        console.log("Updated value is called !")
    }
    
    

    useEffect(() => {
        if(address ){
            getCounterValue()
        }
    },[address]) 
    

    
   

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <h1>The value of Counter is:- {countervalue}</h1>
                <br></br>
                <button  onClick={() => write?.()}>
                    Increment
                </button>
                
            </div>
        </>
    )
    
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the watch param to the useContractRead hook so that it continously fetches the new value of the counter

```
const {data:CounterValue,isError,isLoading} = useContractRead({
        address:"0x9a2b8157348F2D04154e8f79b09EB77D2c506A17",
        abi:abi,
        functionName:"getCounter",
        watch: true
    })
```

Comment: does it auto update and keep sending the data once received ?

Comment: Thank you this worked !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `refetch` from `useContractRead`

```
  const { refetch: refetchProjects } = useContractRead({
    address: contractAddress,
    abi: abi.abi,
    functionName: "getAllProjects",
    walletClient: walletClient,
    onSuccess(data) {
      setAllProjects(data);
    },
    onError(error) {
      showAlert("Error", error);
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    refetchProjects?.();
  }, [isSuccess]);
```